# Getting an exception when trying to perform document-type web service RPC

Tags: java, jax-ws

While trying to run the web service from a standalone application, I am getting an error saying that I have two properties with the same name in class Team. 
My code for this is :

TEAM.JAVA

```
package demo2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public class Team {

    public ArrayList<Player> players;

    public Team(ArrayList<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Team() {

    }

    @WebMethod
    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

}
```

PLAYER.JAVA

```
package demo2;

public class Player {

    public String nam;

    public Player(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.nam = name;
    }

    public Player() {

    }

    public String getNam() {
        return nam;
    }

    public void setNam(String name) {
        this.nam = name;
    }

}
```

PUBLISHER.JAVA

```
package demo2;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;


public class Publisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        players.add(new Player("aa"));
        players.add(new Player("tt"));
        players.add(new Player("ss"));
        players.add(new Player("ab"));
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:12223/demo", new Team(players));
    }

}
```

STACK TRACE:---------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
    at demo2.Publisher.main(Publisher.java:15)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "nam"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String demo2.Player.getNam()
        at demo2.Player
        at public java.util.ArrayList demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers.arg0
        at demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String demo2.Player.nam
        at demo2.Player
        at public java.util.ArrayList demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers.arg0
        at demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "nam"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String demo2.Player.getNam()
        at demo2.Player
        at public java.util.ArrayList demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers.arg0
        at demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String demo2.Player.nam
        at demo2.Player
        at public java.util.ArrayList demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers.arg0
        at demo2.jaxws.SetPlayers

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The property `nam` is accessible both by the (public) field itself and by the getter method. JAXB is apparently interpreting this as being two different attributes with the same name hence the conflict.

Try to make the field private.